# How to call "backward" in a loop with 2 optimizers?

Tags: python, optimization, neural-network, pytorch

I have 2 networks that I'm trying to update:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.distributions import Normal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm

softplus = torch.nn.Softplus()

class Model_RL(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model_RL, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3, 20)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(20, 30)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(30, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = softplus(self.fc3(x))
        return x

class Model_FA(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model_FA, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 20)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(20, 30)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(30, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = softplus(self.fc3(x))
        return x

net_RL = Model_RL()
net_FA = Model_FA()
```

The training loop is

```
inps = torch.tensor([[1.0]])
y = torch.tensor(10.0)

opt_RL = optim.Adam(net_RL.parameters())
opt_FA = optim.Adam(net_FA.parameters()) 

baseline = 0
baseline_lr = 0.1

epochs = 100

for _ in tqdm(range(epochs)):

    for inp in inps:

        with torch.no_grad():
            net_FA(inp)
               
        for layer in range(3):
            out_RL = net_RL(torch.tensor([1.0,2.0,3.0]))
            mu, std = out_RL
            dist = Normal(mu, std)
            update_values = dist.sample() 
            log_p = dist.log_prob(update_values).mean()

            out = net_FA(inp) 
            reward = -torch.square((y - out)) 
            baseline = (1 - baseline_lr) * baseline + baseline_lr * reward

            loss_RL = - (reward - baseline) * log_p            
            opt_RL.zero_grad()
            opt_FA.zero_grad()
            loss_RL.backward()
            opt_RL.step()            

            out = net_FA(inp) 
            loss_FA = torch.mean(torch.square(y - out)) 
            opt_RL.zero_grad()
            opt_FA.zero_grad()
            loss_FA.backward()
            opt_FA.step()



print("Mean: " + str(mu.detach().numpy()) + ", Goal: " + str(y))
print("Standard deviation: " + str(softplus(std).detach().numpy()) + ", Goal: 0ish")
```

I'm getting 2 main errors:

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling .backward()...
```

And when I add `retain_graph=True` to both `backward` calls I get the following

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [30, 1]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 5; expected version 4 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
```

My main question is **how can I make this training work**?

But intermediate questions are:

why does `retain_graph=True` is needed here if I'm using a loop? From [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-computation-graph-in-pytorch-is-created-and-freed/3515/4): "there is no need to use retain_graph=True. In each loop, a new graph is created"

Why does it seem as if the `retain_graph=True` makes training significantly slower (if I remove the other `backward` call)? This doesn't really makes sense to me as in each epoch a new computational graph should be created (and not just one that is being extended).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. See [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the line `baseline = (1 - baseline_lr) * baseline + baseline_lr * reward` causing the error. Because:

- **previous** state of `baseline` is used to get **new** state of `baseline`.
- PyTorch will track all these states inside a graph.
- `backward` will **flush** the graph.
- variable `baseline` of time - **t + 1** will **try to backpropagate** through `baseline` of time - **t**.
- But at time - **t + 1**  graph behind `baseline` of time - **t** doesn't exist.
- This leads to error

Solution:
As you are not **optimizing** variable `baseline` or anything behind `baseline`

- Initialize`baseline` as **torch tensor**.
- **detach** it from graph before updating state.

Try this:

```py
# intialize baseline as torch tensor
baseline = torch.tensor(0.)
baseline_lr = 0.1

epochs = 100

for _ in tqdm(range(epochs)):

    for inp in inps:

        with torch.no_grad():
            net_FA(inp)
               
        for layer in range(3):
            out_RL = net_RL(torch.tensor([1.0,2.0,3.0]))
            mu, std = out_RL
            dist = Normal(mu, std)
            update_values = dist.sample() 
            log_p = dist.log_prob(update_values).mean()

            out = net_FA(inp) 
            reward = -torch.square((y - out)) 

            # detach baseline from graph
            baseline = (1 - baseline_lr) * baseline.detach() + baseline_lr * reward

            loss_RL = - (reward - baseline) * log_p            
            opt_RL.zero_grad()
            opt_FA.zero_grad()
            loss_RL.backward()
            opt_RL.step()            

            out = net_FA(inp) 
            loss_FA = torch.mean(torch.square(y - out)) 
            opt_RL.zero_grad()
            opt_FA.zero_grad()
            loss_FA.backward()
            opt_FA.step()
```

But actually I don't know why you are updating the networks, 3 times for the same input?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I don't know how I missed this. I'm updating it 3 times because this is a simplification of a much larger training loop. I tried to keep the important things to simplify the code for SO